# CocoaTouch: a dictionary that hashes pointers, without NSCopying

Tags: cocoa-touch, data-structures

I'm looking for a better way to do this:

```
id key, value;
NSMutableDictionary dict;
[dict setObject:value forKey:[NSNumber numberWithInt:(int)key]]
```

That is, use an NSDictionary to map from address to object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [CFDictionary](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFDictionaryRef/Reference/reference.html)/CFMutableDictionary.

> Keys for a CFDictionary may be of any C type.

```
const void * CFDictionaryGetValue (
   CFDictionaryRef theDict,
   const void *key
);
```

You'll need to `#import <CoreFoundation/CoreFoundation.h>` and possibly add the CoreFoundation framework to your project.

When creating the dictionary, specify `NULL` for the key and value callback structures to indicate you don't want them to be retained.

Answer (score 0):

If you can, use C++'s map:

```
std::map<id, id> map;
map.insert(std::make_pair(key, value));
```

You'll have to change the file's extension to `.mm`. Also note that it will not retain your values.

Comment: then std::unordered_map, just include ``tr1/unordered_map``